# How do I run C++ code in Geany on Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.04, c++, geany

I want run C++ in Geany, but it's not working.

Before I was trying to run Pascal but it didn't work. Then I installed fpc success run fine.

When I run C++, this error appears in terminal:

```
./geany_run_script.sh: 5: ./geany_run_script.sh: ./untitled: not found


------------------
(program exited with code: 127)
Press return to continue
```

Is there any additional plugin or something else I need to run C++ programs in Geany?

Answer (score 2):

You didn't build the file, you just compiled it.

In your screenshot we can see the compiling command g++ -Wall "-c",
http://bakhtiar.web.id/wp-content/uploads/Screenshot%20from%202013-04-01%2013:15:02.png

which means "Compile and assemble, but do not link".

Answer (score 1):

I could only reproduce this error if the program didn't compile successfully **OR** you did not build it after compiling it. If you've compiled+built it, it's likely that there's an error in your program, which means that `untitled.cpp` did not compile down to the corresponding binary `untitled`, thus raising the `./untitled: not found` error.

Always check the compiler output to see if compilation was successful. You can find it below the code-area. See:

[image: I added an error to reproduce your problem]

Try running a simple Hello World C++ program and check to see if it works.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
   std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: I've tried to compile and success. But the error message appears on the terminal. See it... http://bakhtiar.web.id/wp-content/uploads/Screenshot%20from%202013-04-01%2013:15:02.png

Answer (score 1):

Build the file in Geany as follows, you should be able to execute without any problem after that

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem and the answer was none of the above. I simply hadn't named the Geany file properly. When I saved it I called it loops, I should have called it loops.py

Answer (score 0):

I tried all of the other answers and none worked for me. The easiest way is to add your program file path in **Edit > Preferences > General tab > Startup tab > Project Files** Save this.

Now, go to **Build > Set Build Commands > Execute Commands > Execute** add this as it is below: (don't miss the leading `.`)

```
."/%e"
```

Click OK and that's it. Now **Build > Build** (<kbd>F9</kbd>) and then **Build > Execute** (<kbd>F5</kbd>). Kaboom. Should work now.