# Unable to compile in geany

Tags: command-line, python, c++, c, geany

Whenever I try to compile any file whether c , c++ or python in geany I get this error.

[image: Error pic]

Comment: It appers to me that you are not compiling at all but running your file. What exactly are you doing? Which version of Geany are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to:  [Error running C program compiled with Geany IDE Error Code: 127](https://askubuntu.com/questions/472760/error-running-c-program-compiled-with-geany-ide-error-code-127)

There are at least two possible ways to solve it:

1) Update your `geany` via repository: http://sysads.co.uk/2014/07/install-geany-1-24-1-ide-on-ubuntu-14-04/

2) Follow these steps:

> You only compiled your *source file*, but didn't build your
>   *application*, meaning the linking was not done and the executable was not created. Use the "build" sub-menu from the "build" menu (default
>   shortcut is F9 if I recall correctly) and try again.

Read also: [How run C++ in Geany Ubuntu 12.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/276511/how-run-c-in-geany-ubuntu-12-10)

Hope it help